# Mongodb. Aggregation. $match: [another collection keys]

Tags: mongodb

Users and purchase are two collections.
Purchase collection has reference key 'user'.
I need get entryes from purchase collection that belong to a some users taken by city tag.

```
result = db.users.aggregate([{'$match': {'user_info.city1': 0}}])
db.userset.insert(result['result'])

db.purchase.aggregate([{'$match': {'user': usersarray(?) }}])
```

Can I pass to $match an array of users if there are more a million, and every user have over 10000 purchase? 
Is there another way to do this with aggregation?
This example is contrived and not about embedded documents.

Comment: mongo doesn't do cross collection match, you can however look at mapreduce function, write a mapper (using JS) to load related objects and reduce them using the next method(using JS).

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking. Do you want to use the results of a previous statement in your new aggregation query? Or do you want to use a collection? What is `usersarray`? Perhaps answer these points by editing your question. That would be the best way.

Comment: @AnanthaSharma MapReduce doesn't do "cross collection" either. So not sure what you are getting at. Perhaps you once read a technique referred to as "incremental map reduce", but this only has specific uses, and this does not seem to be one of them

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can very likely pass many users provided your entire query is within the 16MB BSON Document limit. Very likely this is what you meant by your second query:

```
db.purchase.aggregate([{'$match': {'user': {'$in': ['user1', ...'userN']} }}])
```

Comment: 16mb it's sad. It's only about 500000 users (email in unicode). Is there a way to circumvent this restriction?  Are you sure that this restriction applies to Aggregation?

Comment: @kvadrat, you will most likely start noticing other issues before you reach that limit.